# Remove value of multiple list

Tags: python, list

I have a python code. My subject is the following :

*I have a french weather article. I extracted location and i want to keep only location with preposition ["de", "à", "d"].*

For one article of my dataset i have an **index out of range** error. This error if generated by my localisation selection function.

```
def loc_selection(lieu, prep, lon, lat): 
    i=0
    while True:
        if prep[i] not in ["de", "à", "d'"]:
            lieu.pop(i)
            prep.pop(i)
            lon.pop(i)
            lat.pop(i)
            i = i - 1
        i = i + 1
        if i >= (len(prep)):
            break

    return lieu, prep, lon, lat
```

I have 4 list lieu, prep, lon, lat. I want to remove all data in prep field that is not a correct preposition. I also want to remove corresponding data in other lists.

I'm not sure my method is the best. Feel free to apply your own method.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you print us the list which causes the index out of range ? And, since lieu, prep, lon and lat are related to one location you should store them in one single dictionnary instead of 4 lists

Comment: A dictionnary is a key : value yes ? How can i create a dict with 4 value associate ?

Comment: You can have as keys your location ID in string format (basically the index of your lists) and as values you put a nested dictionnary `{lieu:<mon_lieu>, prep:<ma_prep>, lon:<ma_lon>, lat:<ma_lat>}`. You can delete a pair key:value (with your 4 pieces of information) with one single instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `zip`ping the lists together and iterating through them in parallel is a better fit for what you want to do.  The following yields `(lieu, prep, long, lat)` tuples with one of the prefixes:

```
def loc_selector(lieus, preps, longs, lats, prefixes=("de", "à", "d'")):
    for lieu, prep, long, lat in zip(lieus, preps, longs, lats):
        if prep in prefixes:
            yield lieu, prep, long, lat
```

Then you can use `zip` again on that generator to get them back into lists:

```
lieus, preps, longs, lats = zip(*loc_selector(lieus, preps, longs, lats))
```

`zip` will stop automatically at the end of the shortest list.

Comment: Thank for your answer. No need to add a return ?  The original list are updated ?

Comment: The `loc_selector` is a generator. https://www.learnpython.org/en/Generators

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you’re looking to remove elements from all lists keeping order. `frozenset` and `set` can be of use:

```
def remove_from_all(remove, *iterables):
    rem = set(remove)
    return (list(it - rem) for it in map(frozenset, iterables))

remove = [34, 18, 24]
lists = [1,3,18], [34, 13, 5], [64, 24, 10]
print(list(remove_from_all(remove, *lists)))
```

This prints:

```
[[1, 3], [13, 5], [64, 10]]
```

I just used random integers for example so you can see what I’d does as you didn’t provide enough detail on input.

**Note:** this will also remove duplicates, so you can use `itertools.iterfalse` to keep all elements and order without items in remove:

```
def remove_from_all(remove, *iterables):
    rem = set(remove).__contains__
    return (list(filterfalse(rem, it)) for it in iterables)
```